# Get friends photo and name from Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know that we cannot get friend list from Facebook app from user_friends permission - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_1694316010830088

But is it possible to get the same information from invite API?

My app is a quiz game about other friends? For ex. by showing a photo and asking to click on right name.

Can my app be considered as a game?

Comment: You are not allowed to use the invitable_friends endpoint for _anything else_ but inviting people.

Comment: And before you ask it is the same answer for taggable_friends

Comment: @WizKid - what happens if I use any of this for other purpose? Will FB block me?

Comment: Restrict the app and you from ever creating a new app